# How to add pdf_ui_utils in angular 4 typescript project

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, pdf.js

I'm trying to add text selection in PDFJS using the method `renderTextLayer`.

Base from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063213/pdf-js-with-text-selection) you need to add `ui_util.js`, though I'm not sure how to add it in an existing Angular 4 Typescript project.

I tried adding it in `angular-cli.json` like below

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/lib/web/ui_utils.js"
]
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your import to angurla-cli.json looks correct. To use external libraries you also need the typings for the library to make it available in your editor.

For that you have two possibilities:

1. Import the typings from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types) - if available
2. Make the library visible in your project by adding some code to typings.d.ts. I have described in a different [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293797/how-to-import-and-use-particles-js-in-an-angular-angular2-angular4-app) how that can be done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, angular was able to load the js file, the problem is that it's loading it on the client side rather than the server, and throwing the error `exports` is not defined.