# is it possible to enable select and copy content when using pdf.js to preview pdf in chrome

Tags: html, reactjs, pdf.js

I am tried to use `pdf.js` to preview pdf in google chrome browsers, the `pdf.js` dependencies version is `"pdfjs-dist": "^3.9.179"`. This is my demo typescript code in react web app to implement the pdf preview:

```
const initPdf = async () => {
            const pdfJS = await import('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf');
            pdfJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
                window.location.origin + '/pdf.worker.min.js';
            const pdf = await pdfJS.getDocument('lshort-zh-cn.pdf').promise;
            const page = await pdf.getPage(1);
            const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1.5 });
            const canvas: any = canvasRef.current;
      if(!canvas) return;
            const canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;
            const renderContext = { canvasContext, viewport };
            page.render(renderContext);
  }
```

this demo code works fine, but I fount the preview pdf could not select and copy the content, is it possible to enable the select and copy? I have tried like this but the text layer was seperate with the cavas:

```
const initPdf = async () => {
    const pdfJS = await import('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf');
    pdfJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
      window.location.origin + '/pdf.worker.min.js';
    const pdf = await pdfJS.getDocument('lshort-zh-cn.pdf').promise;
    const page = await pdf.getPage(1);
    const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1.5 });
    const canvas: any = canvasRef.current;
    if (!canvas) return;
    const canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;
    const renderContext = { canvasContext, viewport };
    const renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
    renderTask.promise.then(function () {
      const textContent = page.getTextContent();
      return textContent;
    }).then(function (textContent: string) {
      var textLayer = document.querySelector(`.${styles.textLayer}`) as HTMLDivElement;
      textLayer.style.left = canvas.offsetLeft + 'px';
      textLayer.style.top = canvas.offsetTop + 'px';
      textLayer.style.height = canvas.offsetHeight + 'px';
      textLayer.style.width = canvas.offsetWidth + 'px';
      pdfJS.renderTextLayer({
        textContent: textContent,
        container: textLayer,
        viewport: viewport,
        textDivs: []
      });
    });
  }
```

import the pdf viewer css like this:

```
import "pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer.css";
```

I followed the guide from here: [pdf.js with text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063213/pdf-js-with-text-selection). The UI look like this:

[image]

this is part of the css look like:

```
<div className={styles.previewBody}>
            <div className={styles.cavasLayer}>
              <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={{ height: '100vh' }} />

            </div>
            {/*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063213/pdf-js-with-text-selection*/}
            <div className={styles.textLayer}>

            </div>
          </div
```